# Unexpected use of comma operator React

Tags: reactjs, frontend

Line 85:74:   Unexpected use of comma operator  no-sequences
Line 85:153:  Unexpected use of comma operator

```
    <div className={"card text-white bg-success me-auto ms-auto mt-5",res.percentage >= 50 ? "bg-success" : "bg-danger"} style={{maxWidth : "30rem"},{display : translate=== ""? "none":""}}>
```

Comment: you can try and use template literals, it would make conditional statements easier https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score -1):

```
<div className={"card text-white bg-success me-auto ms-auto mt-5 ",res.percentage >= 50 ? "bg-success" : "bg-danger"} style={{maxWidth : "30rem", display : translate=== ""? "none":""}}>
```

You have just done a syntax mistake. When using `style` prop in React you need to pass just one object with all the rules.

Comment: Hi Arthur, thanks for investing time to answer. Please add some more details on solution, so we can better understand it.